# My SKMaps always crashing on load map

Tags: android, dictionary, skmaps

I cant use my map because it always crashing. This is the crash logs

```
12-16 10:44:21.886: E/AndroidRuntime(8958): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 723
12-16 10:44:21.886: E/AndroidRuntime(8958): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-16 10:44:21.886: E/AndroidRuntime(8958):     at com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKMapSurfaceView$7.run(SourceFile:1698)
12-16 10:44:21.886: E/AndroidRuntime(8958):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1485)
12-16 10:44:21.886: E/AndroidRuntime(8958):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1263)
```

Please help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: please post the complete stacktrace.

Comment: that was the complete stacktrace sir jan.

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing we can do with the current bug report. Can you reproduce the issue in the demo project?